# JBoss fails to start from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I recently migrated from Netbeans and GlassFish to Eclipse and JBoss. I have installed the eclipse-jboss tools, and the server runtime is set up properly (afaik at least).

The problem I have is that whenever I try to start JBoss from Eclipse, I get this:

```
20:37:23,853 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
20:37:24,136 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
20:37:24,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
20:37:24,306 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment-mount-provider: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment-mount-provider: JBAS015843: Failed to create temp file provider
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$ServerDeploymentRepositoryImpl.start(DeploymentMountProvider.java:111) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
```

I have googled this and tried all workarounds I could find, including (!!!) giving jboss-as.service root priviliges (EDIT: which is pointless since Eclipse does not even touch systemd in this case). Nothing helps. Could anyone help? It would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is interesting:

SERVER.LOG:

```
20:35:39,344 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "chrisdesktop:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
20:35:39,389 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "chrisdesktop:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
20:35:42,379 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "chrisdesktop:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
20:35:42,907 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "chrisdesktop:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
20:35:43,081 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "chrisdesktop:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
20:35:43,242 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "chrisdesktop:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
20:35:44,851 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "chrisdesktop:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of 1195725856
```

[snip info logs]

```
20:55:29,931 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-15) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.osgi.as.framework.bootstrap: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.osgi.as.framework.bootstrap: JBAS011965: Failed to create Framework services
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.service.FrameworkBootstrapService.start(FrameworkBootstrapService.java:161)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/util/xml/XMLParserActivator
    at org.jboss.as.osgi.service.FrameworkBootstrapService.start(FrameworkBootstrapService.java:139)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.util.xml.XMLParserActivator from [Module "org.jboss.as.osgi:main" from local module loader @7fae4426 (roots: /usr/share/jboss-as/modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 6 more

20:55:29,932 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
20:55:29,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
20:55:30,027 FATAL [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-19) JBAS015577: Error while creating configuration service
20:55:30,028 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-19) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ws.config: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ws.config: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client:main is not found in local module loader @7fae4426 (roots: /usr/share/jboss-as/modules)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.service.ServerConfigService.start(ServerConfigService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client:main is not found in local module loader @7fae4426 (roots: /usr/share/jboss-as/modules)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.util.ModuleClassLoaderProvider.getServerIntegrationClassLoader(ModuleClassLoaderProvider.java:56)
    at org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig.create(AbstractServerConfig.java:201)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.service.ServerConfigService.start(ServerConfigService.java:69)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client:main is not found in local module loader @7fae4426 (roots: /usr/share/jboss-as/modules)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:126) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:841) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1225) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:208) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.util.ModuleClassLoaderProvider.getServerIntegrationClassLoader(ModuleClassLoaderProvider.java:53)
    ... 7 more

20:55:30,065 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "webservices")]): java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client:main is not found in local module loader @7fae4426 (roots: /usr/share/jboss-as/modules)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.util.ModuleClassLoaderProvider.getServerIntegrationClassLoader(ModuleClassLoaderProvider.java:56)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.deployment.DeploymentAspectsProvider.getSortedDeploymentAspects(DeploymentAspectsProvider.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.dmr.WSDeploymentActivator.addDeploymentProcessors(WSDeploymentActivator.java:77)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.dmr.WSDeploymentActivator.activate(WSDeploymentActivator.java:71)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.dmr.WSSubsystemAdd$1.execute(WSSubsystemAdd.java:118)
    at org.jboss.as.server.AbstractDeploymentChainStep.execute(AbstractDeploymentChainStep.java:45)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:311) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09-icedtea]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.jboss.ws.jaxws-client:main is not found in local module loader @7fae4426 (roots: /usr/share/jboss-as/modules)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:126) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94) [snip]
```

Answer (score 4):

On mac I had it with WildFly after(I suppose) copied external file to wildfly dir. As guys said it was permissions issue and

```
chmod -R 777 [wildfly dir]
```

helped. Not that accurate, but fast solution if you are under development cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I see the error - JBAS015843: Failed to create temp file provider.

I guess you are using Windows 7. Windows 7 asked me to give the process permissions to create files in Windows\Temp directory from a separate dialog. You might have to locate that dialog and give permissions. This does not have anything to do with windows service, since you are starting jboss from eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I am running Fedora 17, not Windows. It feels really awkward to give Eclipse (even temporary) root priviliges...I would really like to know what directories JBoss is trying to create stuff in.

Comment: Look for the temp environment variable. You might be running on Fedora with a root user. That is why you might be seeing this issue. If you will have a different profile, you will have a different temp dir with the right permissions.

Answer (score 1):

check permissions set on $JBOSS_HOME/standalone especially $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log directory

for heck of it what does `chmod -R 777 $JBOSS_HOME/standalone` do? not that I recommend this beyond debugging...

as giving jboss-as.service root privileges does not do much, as eclipse does not use that service to run AS7 but runs it manually.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve the issue...strange thing is I have no problem starting JBoss via systemd, so I am guessing we can narrow the problem down to Eclipse. I will post the log output above.

Comment: What version of Eclipse / Jboss tools do you use? Maybe try upgrading to latest?

Comment: Eclipse 4.2.1 and JBoss tools at 3.3.1, everything at latest.

Answer (score 1):

It was a wierd space issue.

```
df -h
```

Above command had issued that there was considerable space in the file mount.
while,

```
df -PhI
```

Had concerns of no space on the mount, Indicating that I-Node was out of space.
Extending more space was the solution followed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to ensure your user is in group jboss-as.

also check if that group has write permissions to the symlinked directories under the /usr/share/jboss-as/standalone

there could be some files owned by root if you started the JbossAS before. And most likely your user cannot write to those files.

Answer (score 0):

I  also faced the same problem when working with eclipse JUNO in windows 7 environment. I was trying to run jboss AS 7.0 server from eclipse juno and I was getting the same errors.

I then realized it may be because I installed jboss EAP 6.0 package under "c:\program files". I then uninstalled my jboss EAP 6.0 and re-install it in "c:\" and point the eclipse's jboss server adapter to new location. This solution works for me!

I don't know why windows 7 treating program files as a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

The error `JBAS015843: Failed to create temp file provider`

is due to the unavailability of enough memory space. Please check the tmp folder under standalone folder of your Jboss. Clear its contents using

```
rm -rfv tmp/*
```

Then restart your Jboss server.